# Analog of select() for monitoring child processes?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, nonblocking

The `select` call in POSIX-compliant systems is useful when carrying out non-blocking I/O, letting one know when a file descriptor is "ready" for an I/O operation. Is there anything analogous for the `waitpid` system call? I know that one can use the `WNOHANG` flag to make an individual `waitpid` call non-blocking, in the same way that one can use, say, the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag to make an individual `recvfrom` socket call non-blocking. However, sometimes the timeout feature offered by `select` is more convenient, and allows one to avoid a loop that repeatedly calls `recvfrom` as quickly as possible; `select` also allows one to monitor multiple file descriptors simultaneously. Is there anything offered by Unix-like systems (or Linux specifically) that gives similar functionality for monitoring child processes?

Comment: What else is in the main polling loop besides `waitpid`? What else [non-child related] are you waiting for? It would help if you would post some representative code as that will shape which syscall to use. Have you looked at `waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG)`? Many apps will establish a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`--the base task can do other things without worrying about the child process terminations (i.e. the signal handler does the `wait` [in blocking mode, because an immediate return is guaranteed]).

Comment: Use just `wait` and check the pid after it returns? For timeout you can use an alarm.

Comment: @CraigEstey apologies for the vagueness of the question; I actually don't have a specific project in mind, was just wondering about general possible options. Writing a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` sounds like exactly what I was thinking of, thank you so much for the insight

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya alarms would also certainly work, although I was wondering about more refined/child process-specific approaches. Thank yoiu for the advice in any case!

Comment: I think outside of non-POSIX linux specific solutions, you can achieve this by starting each process with a parent(read)/child(write) pipe on a fd (e.g., fd 16 in the child) that the child shouldn't close so that EOF received on the parent side corresponds to the child (and all of its descendants) having finished. Then you can use select on the parent ends of the fds.

Comment: @PSkocik That's quite a nice approach for a portable solution, will keep in mind

Comment: It is called the *pipe trick*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to expand on the possibility suggested by Craig Estey, and throw signalfd into the mix.

Instead of setting up a signal handler to handle SIGCHLD, set up signalfd to do the job instead. That way, you'll have a file descriptor that will become ready when SIGCHLD has been signaled, and then you can use select() to wait for it, with a time out.

I've been using signalfd as a way of catching signals for quite a while now. It's Linux specific (OK by the tags you've attached to the question!), and it's far, far easier to handle a signal in the context of the main thread of execution, instead of being limited with what one can do inside a conventional signal handler. The response time to the signal might not be quite so fast, but if an application already has a reactor such as select, or poll, or zmq_poll, or indeed any fd input to any GUI framework's event loop handler, it's an awful lot easier.

Comment: Hadn't heard of signalfd, thank you so much for the tip – this seems like by far the most elegant way of doing this on Linux

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom you're most welcome. It seems a lot of people haven't heard of it, yet it's a most fantastic bit of Linux. I reckon you could pretty much wipe out most of the questions on SO about signal handling if everyone used signalfd. It'll be interesting to see if other *nixes implement something similar, because it is soooo useful.

Comment: @bazza BSDs have something similar with the `EVFILT_SIGNAL` [`kqueue(2)`](https://man.openbsd.org/kqueue.2) event filter. (`kqueue` also can notify you when a specific process exits)

Comment: @Shawn, ah thank you very much, that's fantastic! I shall remember that one :-)